# how to get an index of html element in jquery

Tags: jquery, html, indexing

i have html elements

> ```
> <ul>
> <li>
>     <dl class="details clear">
>         <dt>TIME&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</dt>
>         <dd>09:00:00-10:00:00</dd>
>         <dt>Availible&nbsp;Days&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</dt>
>         <dd>monday,tuesday,wednesday</dd>
>         <dt></dt>
>         <dd>
>         <label class="edit-details white_blue" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">EDIT</label>
>         <label class="delete-details white_red" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">DELETE</label>
>         </dd>
>     </dl>
>     <dl class="details clear">
>         <dt>TIME&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</dt>
>         <dd>10:30:00-11:30:00</dd>
>         <dt>Availible&nbsp;Days&nbsp;:&nbsp;&nbsp;</dt>
>         <dd>monday,tuesday,wednesday</dd>
>         <dt></dt>
>         <dd>
>         <label class="edit-details white_blue" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">EDIT</label>
>         <label class="delete-details white_red" style="float:right;margin-right:10px;">DELETE</label>
>         </dd>
>     </dl>
> </li>
> </ul>
> ```

i want to get the index of edit label, if it is in the **first "dl"** must alert **0** else if it is in the **second "dl"** must alert **1**

So far i did

```
$("label").click(function () {
    var parent_el = $(this).parents('li');
    alert(parent_el.index(this));
});
```

Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("label").click(function () {
    var parent_el = $(this).parents('dl');
    alert($("dl").index(parent_el));
});
```

OR

```
$("label").click(function () {
        var parent_el = $(this).parents('dl');
        alert(parent_el.index());
    });
```

Comment: The index thing might've been a little simplier by default.